# Filtering City by state in java - Using Array

Tags: java

So,

I've an ArrayList with the values of State and City, And I've to check if state are equals to some variable, lets call its "var1" and if this state are equals, I've to get the city names...

I'm creating a menu filter.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label>#{msg['state']}</label>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="mdl-state" value="#{saisReportQueryBean.keyState}" class="form-control">
        <f:ajax listener="#{saisReportQueryBean.Teste()}"/> 
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="#{msg['select_state']}" noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{saisReportQueryBean.keyState}" var="estado" itemValue="#{estado}" itemLabel="#{estado}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label>#{msg['city']}</label>
    <h:selectOneMenu id="mdl-city" value="#{saisReportQueryBean.keyCity}" class="form-control">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="#{msg['select_city']}" noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{saisReportQueryBean.keyCity}" var="cidade" itemValue="#{cidade}" itemLabel="#{cidade}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</div>


When I select the state, I've to update my city itens with just only city in references with the state selected.

Here is my java code.:

protected void updateData() {
        this.reportQuery = new SaisReportQuery();
        this.queryExecuted = false;
        cidades = cidadesIbgeBeanRemote.findAll();
        cidades.sort((f1, f2) -> f1.getMunicipio().compareTo(f2.getMunicipio()));
        Map<String, List<CidadeIbge>> estados = cidades.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(CidadeIbge::getUf));
        setKeyState(estados.keySet());
        getKeyState().toString();
        System.out.println(keyState);       
    }
```

Tks.

Comment: please, make your question complete and clear.

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: All you have done here is tell us your assignment. Show what you have tried and explain exactly where your confusion is.

Comment: See this link, it provides information on how to ask a question in SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The question isn't clear - please see [ask].

Comment: I added some more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry everyone for my uncompleted question.

My point is, when I select some value in my menu, this have to change another menu with the values in referente:

Front Implementation:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" class="col-md-3" id="panel-state">
<label>#{msg['state']}</label>

<h:selectOneMenu id="mdl-state" value="#{saisReportQueryBean.reportQuery.state}" binding="#{uf}" class="form-control input_no_round_corner">
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="#{msg['select_state']}" noSelectionOption="true" />
<f:selectItems value="#{saisReportQueryBean.keyState}" var="estado" itemValue="#{estado}" itemLabel="#{estado}" />
<f:ajax listener="#{saisReportQueryBean.UpdateCityByState(uf.value)}" render=":panel-city" event="change" execute="@this" onevent="initializeChosenFieldsCity">
</f:ajax>
</h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup layout="block" class="col-md-3" id="panel-city">
<label>#{msg['city']}</label>
<h:selectOneMenu id="mdl-city" value="#{saisReportQueryBean.listCidades}" class="form-control input_no_round_corner">
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="#{msg['select_city']}" noSelectionOption="true" />
<f:selectItems value="#{saisReportQueryBean.listCidades}" var="cidade" itemValue="#{cidade.municipio}" itemLabel="#{cidade.municipio}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Back implementation:

```
cidades = cidadesIbgeBeanRemote.findAll();


setKeyState(new ArrayList(estados.keySet()));
getKeyState().toString();
getKeyState().sort((f1, f2) -> f1.compareTo(f2));
```